# How to get grub to boot from a newly encrypted partition

Tags: grub2, luks

I recently encrypted my root partition (sda7) with luksipc. It worked well, I can unlock the partition and mount it when running from a live USB, but the OS doesn't load anymore.

My system has 4 relevant partitions:

- `/dev/sda1` - EFI
- `/dev/sda5` - boot
- `/dev/sda7` - root (now encrypted with LUKS)
- `/dev/sda8` - swap

I only modified sda7, and I haven't modified my `/etc/fstab`, `/etc/crypttab`, and `/etc/grub.d/` files because I didn't know what to put in them. This is what I need help with!

My `/etc/fstab` contains:

```
UUID=211bd0c8-… / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

(221bd0c8-… being the UUID of the *unlocked* sda7)

My `/etc/crypttab` contains an entry for the swap partition (sda8) but nothing for the encrypted sda7 (UUID=8fa9b089-…)

My `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` has:

```
linux /vmlinuz-4.15.0-36-generic root=UUID=221bd0c8-… ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd /initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic
```

I'm not sure how this file is generated, but I used to use grub-cutomizer to edit my boot menu before :)

How can I get my laptop back? (without restoring a backup that is)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I solved it: I started Ubuntu from a Live USB stick, unlocked and mounted sda7, then inside it added an entry in /etc/crypttab for the encrypted partition:

```
sda7_crypt UUID=8fa9b089-… none luks
```

Modified my /etc/fstab entry to use the new mapped name instead of the UUID of the drive:

```
/dev/mapper/sda7_crypt / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

And finally, modified the /etc/default/grub file to add:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.luks.name=8fa9b089-…=sda7_crypt"
```

Then I installed [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/%7Edanielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) on the Live USB, started it, it gave me an error message a button to "change environment" - selected the unlocked sda7 partition, and clicked the checkboxes to mount /boot and /boot/efi.

Then "Save" in grub-customizer, and reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. So your final setup doesn't have /boot partition encrypted, right?
I was trying to set up a whole disk encryption with a single LUKS partition recently (which is mapped into /boot /root /home /var, all encrypted). Last time I did it several years ago I found it non-trivial and gave up (left /boot unencrypted). Now checking again.

Comment: @DmitrySomov you're right, my /boot isn't encrypted. I didn't even know that's possible with a simple grub setup!