# Ubuntu x 2 dual boot: how to get old LUKS-encrypted Ubuntu version back into Grub menu after installing new Ubuntu version in new LUKS partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, luks

I had a LUKS-encrypted Ubuntu 20.04 setup. I [followed my own instructions here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/728750/114401) to shrink the LUKS partition and install Ubuntu 22.04, also LUKS-encrypted. Now, my grub boot menu no longer gives me the option to boot my old LUKS-encrypted Ubuntu 20.04 version. Rather, it just boots the new 22.04 one.

How do I add the LUKS-encrypted Ubuntu 20.04 version back in?

Here's my disk, as shown in gparted while logged into the new Ubuntu 22.04 OS.

Description:

1. `/dev/nvme0n1p1` is the 512 MiB EFI partition
2. `/dev/nvme0n1p2` is the ext4 `/boot` non-encrypted partition for the old Ubuntu 20.04 OS
3. `/dev/nvme0n1p3` is the LUKS-encrypted partition containing a single LVM volume with Ubuntu 20.04 in it (**no longer in the grub menu**)
4. `/dev/nvme0n1p4` is the ext4 `/boot` non-encrypted partition for the new Ubuntu 22.04 OS
5. `/dev/nvme0n1p5` is the LUKS-encrypted partition containing a single LVM volume with Ubuntu 22.04 in it (*is* in the grub menu, and is the OS running right now)

[image]

Possibly useful:

1. For more-experienced people, this answer to a different question may have some clues, but I don't understand it: [How to get grub to boot from a newly encrypted partition](https://askubuntu.com/a/1082774/327339)
2. [How to repair `/boot` on LUKS encrypted harddrive?](https://askubuntu.com/q/844132/327339)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of effort and investigation, I figured it out!

### 1. How to *add* other LUKS-encrypted Linux distributions back to your Grub bootloader startup menu

##### Quick summary

```bash
# 1. Open your `/etc/default/grub` file.
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
# Then manually add these lines to the bottom of that file:
# (required)
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
# (optional)
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y

# 2. Unlock your LUKS-encrypted partitions which contain other bootable
# operating systems. In my case:
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 nvme0n1p3_crypt

# 3. Update your Grub bootloader in your `/boot` partition. 
sudo update-grub
# When I run `update-grub`, my output now includes this line:
#
#       Found Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (20.04) on /dev/mapper/system-root

# 4. Done. Reboot to see and use the new Grub entries!
reboot
```

*Stop here if you just wanted the quick answer.*

##### Details

1. Edit your `/etc/default/grub` file to add the line `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` in it:

   ```bash
   # 1. Open /etc/default/grub in gedit
   sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

   # 2. Now manually add this line to the bottom of it. 
   GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
   # I also recommend this line, but it appears to *not* be necessary:
   GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y

   # 3. Manually save and close the file
   ```

   The `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` line *enables* the Operating System prober, which scans your filesystems for valid operating systems and adds them to the Grub bootloader. This feature is *disabled* by default, so to *enable* it we set `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false`. Here is what the Grub user manual has to say about this: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html:

   > `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER`
   >
   > The `grub-mkconfig` has a feature to use the external os-prober program to discover other operating systems installed on the same machine and generate appropriate menu entries for them. It is disabled by default since automatic and silent execution of os-prober, and creating boot entries based on that data, is a potential attack vector. Set this option to `false` to enable this feature in the `grub-mkconfig` command.

   Note to self: though it appears to *not* be necessary: if the above ever doesn't work by itself, try adding `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y` too. From the link above:

   > `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK`
   >
   > If set to `y`, `grub-mkconfig` and `grub-install` will check for encrypted disks and generate additional commands needed to access them during boot. Note that in this case unattended boot is not possible because GRUB will wait for passphrase to unlock encrypted container.
2. Unlock all LUKS-encrypted partitions which contain operating systems you'd like to add to your Grub menu.

   In my case, my old Ubuntu 20.04 OS is in my `/dev/nvme0n1p3` partition, as explained in my question.

   Note: I like to look at my partitions in the `gparted` GUI partition editor.

   So, here is how to unlock that partition:

   ```bash
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 nvme0n1p3_crypt
   # You'll need to enter your `sudo` password, as well as the LUKS encryption
   # password. It won't show anything while you type them.

   # If you have other LUKS-encrypted partitions, unlock them now too. Ex:
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p6 nvme0n1p6_crypt
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 sda2_crypt
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 sda3_crypt
   # etc.
   ```

   For additional help, see `man cryptsetup`. Notice that the `luksOpen` option is equivalent to `open --type luks`.
3. Now that your LUKS-encrypted partitions are unlocked, and you have told Grub to search for other operating systems in your filesystems, update the Grub bootloader:

   ```bash
   sudo update-grub
   ```

   In its output, look for lines like this, showing that it is finding and adding operating systems to the Grub menu:

   ```
   Found Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (20.04) on /dev/mapper/system-root
   ```

   Full example command and output for me, with that line above in the output:

   ```bash
   $ sudo update-grub
   Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
   Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
   Generating grub configuration file ...
   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-32-generic
   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-32-generic
   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-60-generic
   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-60-generic
   Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
   Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
   Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
   Found Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (20.04) on /dev/mapper/system-root
   Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
   done
   ```

   To verify the new Grub menu entries, you can manually open the file at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and look for `menuentry` entries after the comment in that file which says `### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###`. Do not edit that file directly.

##### Troubleshooting, debugging, & extra info.

1. When running `sudo update-grub`, if you see these lines in the output:

   ```
   Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
   Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
   Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
   ```

   ...then it means you forgot to add `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` to your `/etc/default/grub` file.
2. If you run `sudo update-grub` with*out* having first unlocked all of your LUKS-encrypted partitions containing bootable operating systems, then those operating systems will be **removed** from your Grub menu (if they were previously present) when you run `update-grub` (see the next section). If your find yourself in this situation, simply boot into whatever Linux OS that is available in the Grub menu, and follow the steps above to add the other OS's back into the Grub menu.
3. You can see which partitions are unlocked by looking at the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `lsblk`.

   1. With only my running partition (`/dev/nvme0n1p5`) unlocked (ie: right after a reboot), here's what my output looks like. Notice that in both cases, only `nvme0n1p5_crypt` is shown:

      ```bash
      # 1. `sudo fdisk -l | grep -i mapper` output:
      $ sudo fdisk -l | grep -i mapper
      Disk /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p5_crypt: 870.4 GiB, 934587400192 bytes, 1825366016 sectors

      # 2. `lsblk` output:
      $ lsblk
      NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
      loop0                 7:0    0     4K  1 loop  /snap/bare/5
      loop1                 7:1    0  63.3M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1778
      loop2                 7:2    0  63.3M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1822
      loop3                 7:3    0  72.9M  1 loop  /snap/core22/522
      loop4                 7:4    0 240.6M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/2356
      loop5                 7:5    0 239.8M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/2391
      loop6                 7:6    0 400.8M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
      loop7                 7:7    0 346.3M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
      loop8                 7:8    0 452.4M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-42-2204/56
      loop9                 7:9    0  91.7M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
      loop10                7:10   0  45.9M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/582
      loop11                7:11   0  45.9M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/638
      loop12                7:12   0  49.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/17950
      loop13                7:13   0  49.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/18357
      loop14                7:14   0   304K  1 loop  /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/49
      loop15                7:15   0   428K  1 loop  /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/57
      nvme1n1             259:0    0   1.8T  0 disk  
      nvme0n1             259:1    0 953.9G  0 disk  
      ├─nvme0n1p1         259:2    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
      ├─nvme0n1p2         259:3    0   1.4G  0 part  
      ├─nvme0n1p3         259:4    0    80G  0 part  
      ├─nvme0n1p4         259:5    0   1.5G  0 part  /boot
      └─nvme0n1p5         259:6    0 870.4G  0 part  
        └─nvme0n1p5_crypt 253:0    0 870.4G  0 crypt /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                                     /
      ```
   2. Now, *after* running `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 nvme0n1p3_crypt` to also unlock that LUKS-encrypted partition, here's what I see. Notice that I now see `nvme0n1p3_crypt` and `/dev/mapper/system-root` as well, where `/dev/mapper/system-root` is the Logical Volume (LVM) within the `/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3` LUKS-encrypted partition:

      ```bash
      # 1. `sudo fdisk -l | grep -i mapper` output:
      $ sudo fdisk -l | grep -i mapper
      Disk /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p5_crypt: 870.4 GiB, 934587400192 bytes, 1825366016 sectors
      Disk /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt: 80 GiB, 85903540224 bytes, 167780352 sectors
      Disk /dev/mapper/system-root: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors

      # 2. `lsblk` output:
      $ lsblk
      NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
      loop0                 7:0    0     4K  1 loop  /snap/bare/5
      loop1                 7:1    0  63.3M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1778
      loop2                 7:2    0  63.3M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1822
      loop3                 7:3    0  72.9M  1 loop  /snap/core22/522
      loop4                 7:4    0 240.6M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/2356
      loop5                 7:5    0 239.8M  1 loop  /snap/firefox/2391
      loop6                 7:6    0 400.8M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
      loop7                 7:7    0 346.3M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
      loop8                 7:8    0 452.4M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-42-2204/56
      loop9                 7:9    0  91.7M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
      loop10                7:10   0  45.9M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/582
      loop11                7:11   0  45.9M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/638
      loop12                7:12   0  49.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/17950
      loop13                7:13   0  49.8M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/18357
      loop14                7:14   0   304K  1 loop  /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/49
      loop15                7:15   0   428K  1 loop  /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/57
      nvme1n1             259:0    0   1.8T  0 disk  
      nvme0n1             259:1    0 953.9G  0 disk  
      ├─nvme0n1p1         259:2    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
      ├─nvme0n1p2         259:3    0   1.4G  0 part  
      ├─nvme0n1p3         259:4    0    80G  0 part  
      │ └─nvme0n1p3_crypt 253:1    0    80G  0 crypt 
      │   └─system-root   253:2    0    80G  0 lvm   
      ├─nvme0n1p4         259:5    0   1.5G  0 part  /boot
      └─nvme0n1p5         259:6    0 870.4G  0 part  
        └─nvme0n1p5_crypt 253:0    0 870.4G  0 crypt /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                                     /
      ```
4. Note: for UUID (Universal Unique Identifier) numbers for each partition, run this:

   ```bash
   blkid
   ```
5. Note that 3 of the main disk-related files to be aware of are the following. View them with `cat`:

   ```bash
   # filesystem table (fstab)
   cat /etc/fstab

   # Encrypted table
   cat /etc/crypttab

   # User-editable Grub config file
   # (read and used by `sudo update-grub`)
   cat /etc/default/grub

   # NON-user-editable final grub config file on your `/boot` partition
   # (created or updated by `sudo update-grub`)
   cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```

### 2. How to *remove* other LUKS-encrypted Linux distributions from your Grub bootloader startup menu

To remove all but the running operating system from the Grub boot menu, simply reboot into your desired operating system (this locks all other LUKS-encrypted partitions again), and run:

```bash
sudo update-grub
```

Since no other LUKS-encrypted partitions are unlocked, they'll be automatically removed from the Grub bootloader. Here's what that command and output looks like for me:

```bash
$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-60-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-60-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

If you have a single, shared `/boot` partition for all of your operating systems (unliked me), then that's it! Running `sudo update-grub` in this operating system will have updated that single `/boot` partition, affecting the Grub bootloader used to boot. Or, if you are in your *latest-installed* operating system, which updates the `/boot` partition actually used by your Grub bootloader, that's it!

*But*, if you're in any other operating system, it will have updated *its own*, *old* `/boot` partition instead of the latest one actually used to boot. In that case, you probably need to remount the latest `/boot` partition into the `/boot` dir of your filesystem and then run `sudo update-grub` again, *or* perhaps there is some sort of `chroot` magic you can run. However, I didn't have time for that, so here's a dirty hack I did:

##### Quick summary:

I simply manually copied the newly-created `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file into the correct location on the actual (latest) boot partition, since that `/boot` path it was created in is on the old (now unused) boot partition.

##### Details:

1. I booted into my `/dev/nvme0n1p3` Ubuntu 20.04 OS, which had automatically mounted the old (now wrong/unused) `/dev/nvme0n1p2` boot partition into the filesystem at path `/boot`. I ran `sudo update-grub` to update that (now wrong/unused) `/dev/nvme0n1p2` boot partition at path `/boot`.
2. I opened a GUI file browser and double-clicked on the new boot partition at `/dev/nvme0n1p4`, to automatically mount it into the filesystem at path `/media/gabriel/abcd-1234-efgh-abcdefghij`. In other words, when I am logged into Ubuntu 20.04 in partition `/dev/nvme0n1p3`, then path `/media/gabriel/abcd-1234-efgh-abcdefghij` is *the exact same* as path `/boot` when I am logged into the Ubuntu 22.04 OS on partition `/dev/nvme0n1p5`!
3. Dirty hack: back up the old grub.cfg file and copy the new one into its place.
4. Summary of the commands:

   ```bash
   # running on the Ubuntu 20.04 OS: forcibly remove the Ubuntu 22.04 entry
   # from the Grub boot menu
   #--------------------------------------------

   # run withOUT first unlocking the Ubuntu 22.04 LUKS partition, so that the
   # Ubuntu 22.04 Grub entry will be removed from the "/boot/grub/grub.cfg"
   # file
   sudo update-grub  

   # manually mount the latest boot dir by double-clicking it in your file
   # manager

   # back up the old grub.cfg file in the new /boot dir
   sudo mv /media/gabriel/abcd-1234-efgh-abcdefghij/grub/grub.cfg \
       /media/gabriel/abcd-1234-efgh-abcdefghij/grub/grub.cfg.bak

   # dirty hack: copy over the Ubuntu 20.04-created grub.cfg file to the 
   # latest /boot dir mounted at this other place
   sudo cp /boot/grub/grub.cfg \
       /media/gabriel/abcd-1234-efgh-abcdefghij/grub/grub.cfg

   # now reboot, and all you'll see in the Grub boot menu is the old Ubuntu
   # 20.04 entry, *not* the new Ubuntu 22.04 entry
   reboot
   ```

   Another dirty hack to undo the previous dirty hack:

   To undo this, simply restore the old `grub.cfg` file which you had
   previously backed up as `grub.cfg.bak`:

   ```bash
   sudo mv /media/gabriel/abcd-1234-efgh-abcdefghij/grub/grub.cfg.bak \
       /media/gabriel/abcd-1234-efgh-abcdefghij/grub/grub.cfg
   ```

### References:

1. Mostly my own trial and error, but also:
2. Google search for [grub Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions](https://www.google.com/search?q=grub+Warning%3A+os-prober+will+not+be+executed+to+detect+other+bootable+partitions.&oq=grub+Warning%3A+os-prober+will+not+be+executed+to+detect+other+bootable+partitions.&aqs=chrome..69i57.1339j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
3. Where I first learned about adding `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` to `/etc/default/grub`: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/warning-os-prober-will-not-be-executed-to-detect-other-bootable-partitions/57849
4. `man update-grub`
5. ***** https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html
6. `man 8 grub-mkconfig`
7. `man cryptsetup`
8. [Why do I get "Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions." after running "apt upgrade"?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1414333/327339)
9. My other question: [Unix & Linux: How to get a dual boot (2 Linux OSs) system working when both are LUKS-encrypted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/729247/114401)
10. [How to repair /boot on LUKS encrypted harddrive?](https://askubuntu.com/q/844132/327339)
11. [Adding debian installed on LUKS partition to boot option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/602199/114401)
12. [How to get grub to boot from a newly encrypted partition](https://askubuntu.com/q/1082131/327339) <==
13. [Ubuntu install with mdadm and multiple luks partitions](https://askubuntu.com/q/1365389/327339)
14. [GRUB Bootloader with root LUKS encryption: Only grub shell](https://superuser.com/q/1536669/425838)
15. `man 5 crypttab`, and https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crypttab.5.html